# How to Convert Mono<FilePart> to byte[]?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc

I want to store my excel file into my database using reactive programming. In non-reactive it is easy to do but I cannot do it similarly in reactive, What should I write to store it into my mongo database?

My Controller

```
@PostMapping(path = "/file",consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
    public HttpStatus file(@RequestPart("files") Mono<FilePart> file) {
        return Service.save(excel);
    }
```

My Service

```
public HttpStatus save(Mono<FilePart> filePartMono) {
        //what to do here to save my file into database
    }
```

Entity

```
@Collection("data")
public class Excel {
    @Id
    int id;
    private byte[] file;
}
```

Comment: its tricky because FilePart can only write to a file and not output it's contents. first, 
you need to subscribe on the Mono, so "return filePartMono.then( {<code here>});"
inside the code to execute, open a Try-With-Resources creating a new File, and use the FilePart's method "transferTo". then, read the file and you can get the bytes from it.
i don't have a better answer...

Answer (score 0):

While working with reactive programming you should actually work with `Mono` and `Flux` so that your application is really reactive. The consequence of this is that you must change the return type of your service and controller methods to return `Mono<HttpStatus>` instead. Your complete application should be reactive (from the REST API down to the database) so that you can fully benefit from the reactive stack.

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/file", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
             produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<HttpStatus> file(@RequestPart("files") Mono<FilePart> file) {
    return Service.save(excel);
}
```

In your service you can do as follows:

```java
public Mono<HttpStatus> save(Mono<FilePart> filePartMono) {
    return filePartMono.flatMap { filePart -> // you need flatMap assuming your mongo repository also returns a Mono
        byte[] bytes = // convertion to byte[]

        // save it to the database
    }.map { mongoRepositoryResponse ->
        // depending on the response from mongo repository you compute HttpStatus
    }
}
```

Comment: @Koni, did this help? Let me know if something is unclear.